# Why is the return type of isdigit() int instead of boolean?

Tags: c++

I was reading the cplusplus reference for the [isdigit()](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isdigit) function, where I got this,

```
int isdigit ( int c );
```

> Return Value: A value different from zero (i.e., true) if indeed c is
> a decimal digit. Zero (i.e., false) otherwise.

What does this term "different from zero" indicate, I mean why we can't just stick to 0 or 1.
Also when I tested this function, it is always returning either 1 or 0, then why simply documentation can't say that isdigit function returns 1, instead of saying "different from zero".

Comment: `isdigit` comes from C. Back in the olden days, there was no `bool` type in C

Comment: It is not uncommon for C implementations to return the output of math calculations that result in zero vs not-zero values.

Comment: It's also not required to return exactly `1` for all digits.  These functions are typically done using a single lookup table that encodes all the character traits in different bits of an integer; it's entirely possible for `isdigit` to return the flag meaning "it's a digit" and `isctrl` to return the flag meaning "it's a control character"

Comment: Sadly, that documentation is misleading.  It says "A value different from zero *(i.e., true)* if indeed c is a decimal digit. Zero (i.e., false) otherwise." (emphasis mine).  "different from zero" does NOT mean `true` - it means not zero.  So returning 2, 18, INT_MAX, -1 are all valid "different from zero" return values (as @BenVoigt points out).

Comment: @franji1: Well, *true* (aka truthy) and `true` are different, but the site does say `true` because it’s bad.

Comment: Note that it takes an `int` as a parameter too. That's not a UTF-32 code unit that's just an `int`. This is because the original concept of `int` was that it was the fastest type the CPU could operate on. It's also because when parameters were originally passed in C they were promoted via integer promotion. So that alone should tell you how old this method is.

Comment: cplusplus.com is unreliable Prefer [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit).

Answer (score 2):

The reason is cross compatibility with C.

C itself didn't acquire a Boolean type until C99 and while that was over 20 years ago there's actually little justification for changing the definition of a widely used library function.

A explicit Boolean type has little practical advantage over the conventional use of 0 for false and non-zero for true other than readability.

By different from zero it means 'not zero'. It's near universal computing convention that when encoding Boolean values as numerical values 0 represents 'false' and all other values can be used to represent 'true'.

In general that's not something to worry about because constructs like `if(isdigit(c))` will work because `if()` conforms to the same convention (in C and C++).

But if you're writing something like `count+=isdigit(c)` to perhaps count the number of digits in a string you may not get the answer you want.

As pointed out in the comments implementations may have reason for not returning 1 as true.